# Interesting problem on uniqueness of polygon

Tags: geometry

Given n points in a Cartesian system, prove that there is only one n-sided polygon that can be drawn through these points. It isn't a homework question, I thought of it myself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's false, unless the polygon must be convex.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė it is false even when we assume the polygon is convex. It is possible none of the polygons formed using those $n$-points are convex.

Comment: Given 3 points in the plane. You can construct a triangle whose vertex are these points and you can construct a triangle too whose sides midpoints are these points.

Comment: And do you know the notion of convex hull of a set? I suppose it is interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.  Below are three polygons formed from congruent sets of points.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a lot more specific.

- Do the points have to be vertices of the polygon, or is it enough that some edge of it passes through the point?
- Does the polygon have to be non-self-intersecting/convex/regular/...?

You probably also have to require that no three of the points lie on a straight line.